# can't view images stored on mounted network drive on linux webserver

Tags: apache-httpd, url

I have a network drive mounted at `/home/lv_admin/uslonsnas001` where I have stored images.  The mount point and all sub folders have rwx mod 775 privileges.  My PHP script moves the images to this mount but Apache cannot view the images afterwards.  My webpage (located in `/var/www/`) has the image path set to:

```
/home/lv_admin/uslonsnas001/BoardTest/2011/5/29/10/35/17788/Images/E_1-U23.jpg
```

The `/var/log/apache2/error.log` shows an error of:

```
[error] [client 128.251.109.244] File does not exist: /var/www/home, referer: 
http://uslonsweb003.us.alcatel-lucent.com/AOI/repairtool/repairindex.php
```

so, it looks like Apache is trying to treat my image path as a relative link but I think it should be a symbolic link.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: From the log, it looks as though it's complaining that `/var/www/home` doesn't exist. Does it?

Comment: It would help if we could see this `repairindex.php` code, but then again we could say: move it back to stackoverflow.com :) Anyhow - needs more information cuz there could be at least 4 directions where to look at..

Answer (score 1):

Apache consider urls are either relative or absolute w.r.t. the *site* folder, not the root of the system.

You can work around this using symlinks, and activating the FollowSymlinks option. Refer to [apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html).